# Is 塔拉費薩爾 an appropriate transliteration of my name?

Tags: traditional-characters, names, transliteration

My name is `Talha Faisal` when I try to translate my name into Chinese (traditional) language, I got **塔拉費薩爾** `Ta la fei sar` not `Talha Faisal`
How can I write my name in Chinese?

Comment: Is the "h" silent in your name?

Comment: @Betty, acctually not. You can listen my name here (Bengali) https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=bn&tl=hi&text=%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%B9%E0%A6%BE%20%E0%A6%AB%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%B8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B2

Comment: In that case, 塔拉費薩爾 is not accurate because it's missing the "h" sound. 塔爾哈·費薩爾 would be more accurate.

Comment: @Betty thank you so much. Would you post this comment as answer, so I can accept

Comment: OK. Done as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP has clarified that the "h" in the name is not silent, 塔拉費薩爾 is not an accurate transliteration because it's missing the "h" sound. 塔爾哈·費薩爾 would be more accurate.

Note that Chinese is full of homophones so it is not the only possible transliteration. However, the characters used here are all commonly used and quite conventional in transliteration so I would say it's quite safe.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to get `塔拉·費薩爾`(`Tǎlā Fèisà'ěr`) instead of `Talha Faisal`. Because there is no Chinese character has a romanisation (pinyin) in `lha`, `fai` and `sal`. Alternatively, Chinese characters have `lā`, `fèi` and `sà'ěr`.
It is similar to that you get `Talha Faisal` instead of `Talhat Faysal`(`طلحة فيصل`).

Comment: So, if in chinese `塔拉·費薩爾(Tǎlā Fèisà'ěr)` is the more accurate ?

Comment: In fact, you don't have to submit `塔拉·費薩爾` to governments, banks and other facilities in Taiwan, Hong Kong and Macao. Because the line of name in Chinese is not mandatory to foreign citizens.

Comment: For more accurate, you can visit [Arabic Transliteration Table to Chinese](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/Wikipedia:%E5%A4%96%E8%AA%9E%E8%AD%AF%E9%9F%B3%E8%A1%A8/%E9%98%BF%E6%8B%89%E4%BC%AF%E8%AA%9E)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 泰勒海 費薩爾? This come out by googling "Talha" and  "Faisal" respectively.
Actually, you can choose any word you like if the pronunciation is similar.

Comment: got this from google translate